# Network UNCLAIMED Realtek d723 Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, wireless

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 on HP bs179tx laptop, but I am unable to connect to wireless networks. When I checked `sudo lshw -C network`, it is displaying `*-network UNCLAIMED`.

Comment: What is your kernel version?  `uname -r`

Answer (score 2):

With a temporary working internet connection by ethernet, tethered or whatever means possible, open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install build-essential dkms git
uname -r
```

The last command will give you your kernel version; for example 4.13.0-32-generic. If your kernel version is 4.11 or higher, continue with the following:

```
git clone -b 4.11-up https://github.com/jeremyb31/rtl8723de.git
sudo dkms add ./rtl8723de
sudo dkms build rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414
```

If your kernel version is 4.10 or lower, then do:

```
git clone -b 4.10-down https://github.com/jeremyb31/rtl8723de.git
sudo dkms add ./rtl8723de
sudo dkms build rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414
```

In either case, reboot and your wireless should be working.

**EDIT**: The fact that your dkms status shows ‘built’ and not ‘installed’ suggests that there were problems, most likely errors, in the process I suggested. These errors cannot be ignored; they must be identified and fixed before the driver will build and install properly. Let’s start over. If, at any time, there are errors *STOP* and post them so we can fix it and proceed.

From the terminal:

```
sudo dkms remove rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414 --all
sudo rm -rf rtl8723de
git clone -b 4.10-down https://github.com/jeremyb31/rtl8723de.git
sudo dkms add ./rtl8723de
```

If there are errors here, *STOP* and report them.

```
sudo dkms install rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414
```

If there are errors here, *STOP* and report them.

If all goes without error, please check again:

```
sudo dkms status
```

We hope you see:

> rtl8723de, 5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414,
>   4.10.0-28-generic, x86_64: installed

If so, try:

```
sudo modprobe 8723de
```

Any improvement?

Comment: Kernal version is 4.10.0-28-generic

Comment: All commands executed successfully. I restarted laptop, but unable to connect to WLAN & output of sudo lshw -C network command is still UNCLAIMED.

Comment: Please let me know if any other workaround is available

Comment: I executed all commands for kernel 4.10-down. There are no errors. But still after restart it is UNCLAIMED

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the command: `sudo dkms status` and also `lsmod | grep 8723` and also: `sudo modprobe rtl8723de`. Is secure boot on or off? It needs to be off.

Comment: prashasti@Prashasti:~$ sudo dkms status
rtl8723de, 5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414, 4.10.0-28-generic, i686: built
prashasti@Prashasti:~$ lsmod | grep 8723
prashasti@Prashasti:~$ sudo modprobe rtl8723de
modprobe: FATAL: Module rtl8723de not found in directory /lib/modules/4.10.0-28-generic
prashasti@Prashasti:~$ uname -r
4.10.0-28-generic

Comment: prashasti@Prashasti:~$ sudo dkms status
rtl8723de, 5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414, 4.10.0-28-generic, i686: built

Comment: prashasti@Prashasti:~$ lsmod | grep 8723
prashasti@Prashasti:~$ sudo modprobe rtl8723de
modprobe: FATAL: Module rtl8723de not found in directory /lib/modules/4.10.0-28-generic

Comment: How about: `sudo modprobe 8723de`?

Comment: modprobe: FATAL: Module 8723de not found in directory /lib/modules/4.10.0-28-generic

Comment: Please see my edit above in a few minutes.

Comment: prashasti@Prashasti:~$ sudo dkms status
rtl8723de, 5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414, 4.10.0-28-generic, i686: installed
prashasti@Prashasti:~$ sudo modprobe 8723de
modprobe: FATAL: Module 8723de not found in directory /lib/modules/4.10.0-28-generic
prashasti@Prashasti:~$

Comment: prashasti@Prashasti:~$ sudo dkms status
rtl8723de, 5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414, 4.10.0-28-generic, i686: installed

Comment: prashasti@Prashasti:~$ sudo modprobe 8723de
modprobe: FATAL: Module 8723de not found in directory /lib/modules/4.10.0-28-generic
prashasti@Prashasti:~$

Comment: I am connected now to Wireless network :)